# Is it the bad practice or not for using override variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I do not yet understand much about the performance of Javascript. I have used `my_var` and overriding it again and again in my function with an `each()` loop as below.

```
function lookupObjs(obj) {
    var my_var = jQuery; //or $
    if (Object.keys(obj).length != 0) {
        return my_var.each(obj, function (ins, val) {
            my_var = ins;
            if (my_var === 'holiday') {    
                console.log("holiday : " + my_var);
            }
            if (my_var === 'work') {    
                console.log("work : " + my_var);
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log(obj)    
    }
}
```

Comment: Readability is very poor!

Comment: oh my god how poor is it?

Comment: Friends Please help to explain me how to make this function better then this ?

Comment: Basically the variable name my_var has no relation with either `jquery` or `ins`. And yes, this overriding is without any purpose or sense here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to override `my_var` in the loop, you could just use `ins`:

```
return my_var.each(obj, function (ins, val) {
    if (ins === 'holiday') {
        console.log("holiday : " + ins);
    }
    if (ins === 'work') {
        console.log("work : " + ins);
    }
});
```

It's also not good practice to override variables this way - it's a lot clearer if you just create new variables with obvious names; once they go out of scope they'll be garbage collected.

Comment: In fact my_var is not needed at all. You can just use the variable named jQuery directly instead.